# On any finite field, adding the identity element a finite amount of times will result to the neutral element

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Show that if you add the identity element ($1$) a finite amount of times will result to the neutral element ($0$).

I started with saying that in every field there's an element $a \in F$ so that $a + 1 =0$. But I'm not even sure if this is true because I'm not sure about the example in $\mathbb{R}$. I thought that if $F = \mathbb{R}$ so $a = -1$.

True or not true, I don't really know how to continue further here.

Comment: Just to understand, have you covered the notion of *order* (or *period*) of an element in a (finite) group?

Comment: No, we have just started to talk about *Fields* in Linear Algebra 1 course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming basically no background, consider the elements
$$
1, \quad 1+ 1, \quad 1+ 1 + 1, \quad \dots  \quad, \underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{n}, \quad \dots
$$
Since $F$ is finite, they cannot all be distinct. So there exist $n < m$ such that
$$
\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{n} =
\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{m} = 
\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{n} + 
\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{m-n},
$$
so adding to both sides the opposite of $\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{n}$ you get
$$
0 = \underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{m-n},
$$
with $m - n > 0$.

Comment: truely elegant!

Comment: @shobon, thanks! It is really a standard argument when introducing the notion of the order of an element in a group.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this proof somewhere before but I had a hard time understanding what's standing behind it. Aren't the elements $1, 1+1, 1+1+1,...$ the elements of $F=\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @Georgey, you are given an *arbitrary* finite field $F$. You take one of its elements, namely $1$, and start summing it with itself several times. You should have covered the examples of the fields $\Bbb{Z} / p \Bbb{Z}
$, for $p$ *any* prime, not just $p = 2$.

Comment: Going over and over your proof made everything clear, just let me know I got it right. There must be at least one element so that $\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{n} =
\underbrace{1+ \dots + 1}_{m}$ because it is an infinite series under a finite field, and if all of the elements were distinct the field was not finite but infinite.

Comment: @Georgey, precisely. In a slightly more formal way (which is not truly necessary), you have a function $n \mapsto \underbrace{1 + \dots + 1}_{n}$. This is a function from the infinite set $\Bbb{Z}$ to the finite set $F$, so it cannot be injective. (Also, call it a *sequence*, not a series.)

Answer (score 1):

**Proof**
Let $|F| = n$, then $\{1,2\cdot 1,3\cdot 1,\cdots, (n+1)\cdot 1\}$ cannot be all distinct. Thus suppose WLOG $a>b$ and $a\cdot 1 = b\cdot 1\Longrightarrow (a-b)\cdot 1 = 0$.

This says that Char $F>0$.

Show that Char $F = p$ where $p$ is a prime.
 Suppose not, then let char $F= n = c\cdot d$ where $1<c<n$ and $1<d<n$ are natural numbers. Then
$$1+1+\cdots + 1 = (1+1+\cdots +1)(1+1+\cdots +1) = 0$$
LHS is $n$ times the sum, right hand side is the product of $c$ and $d$ times the sum. Then since $c<n$ and $d<n$, both factor are non-zero, but their product is zero. Contradiction since in a field there is no zero divisor.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Describe the subring generated by 1. Rather, describe the subring generated by 1 in any ring in terms of the free rings.

Comment: I don't think I'm supposed to do it using *Rings* as we haven't learned this Algebraic Structure. We were talking about *Fields* in class.

Answer (score 0):

take a finite field of characteristic p

then $1 + 1 + \cdots + 1 = p = 0$

Comment: Wouldn't it be a special case?

Comment: @Georgey, what?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: @Georgey, why not

Comment: @shobon, the question occurs while dealing with an introduction to the notion of characteristic, so you cannot appeal to the latter.

Comment: all finite fields have prime characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

if $1,2,3,...$ were all distinct, the field would infinite, hence $n=m$ for some $m<n$ and $n-m=0$

Comment: I think you should distinguish more clearly between *integers* and *integer multiples* of the element $1 \in F$.